# GraphQL Query with Angular and Apollo

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I have a query that works perfect in Playground, but when I try to put it in Angular and get datas result, it doesn't work.

This is my query :

```
query countFeatureInProject {
  commitsConnection (where: {
    name_not_starts_with : "Merge"
    branch :{
      name_starts_with: "feature"
      project: {
        name: "myProjectName"
      }
    }
  })
  {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

My question is : Can I write my query in Angular just like I do when I use Playground ?

Thanks for your attention !

**EDIT**: If you need more details, please, don't hesitate !

Comment: This should be possible! Do you see an error message?

Comment: Hello nburk ! No return, no error, nothing... A console.log in the result subscribe return undefined, that's all I know...

Comment: can you please show your code that calls that query?  also I would recommend checking out this blog post about the best way to query GraphQL with Angular - https://medium.com/the-guild/apollo-angular-code-generation-7903da1f8559